# Recurse loop trace

Tags: c, recursion

I have written the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void recurse();
int main()
{
recurse();
return 0;
}
void recurse()
{
    static int n=987654321;
    if(n==0)
        return ;
    printf("%d",n%10);
    n=n/100;
    int a=n;
    recurse();
    if(a!=0)
    printf("%d",a%10);
}
```

I am not understanding why the output is coming 135799753?
What I thought the answer to be was 135799 because after printing the first 9 after 1357 n will become 9 and hence n/100 will be zero so the recurse function will return to the main without printing anything.
Please correct me where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps use a debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of program is correct. Your output also consists of these values -

```
if(a!=0)
printf("%d",a%10);
```

Value of `a` is also printed if it is not `0`. But the values are printed from last to first because of these statements after the recursion call.

You consider output to be `135799`. Second `9` being value of `a%10` but value of `a%10` from previous recursion calls is also to be printed as those statements get executed after the end of recursion call.

You can see in this [example](https://ideone.com/riYrHJ).